# Remove Span Class From Woocommerce Price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I Want to remove span class autour the price

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>15</span>
```

How i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "woocommerce_get_price_html" filter to remove class from span tag like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_class_price_html', 10, 2 );
function remove_class_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    return str_replace( 'woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol', '', $price );
}
```

Or else you can use **preg_replace** to remove class from both span tags.